# Shell command to find the highest version of kernel from list

Tags: shell, command, kernel

Shell command to find the highest version of kernel from below list

```
       kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-2.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sort` has an option (`-V`) to sort by version number:

```
$ cat kernels
       kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-2.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
$ sort -V kernels
       kernel-2.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

To get only the newest version, use `tail`:

```
$ sort -V kernels | tail -1
       kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

If you want the newest first, then sort in reverse order (`-r`):

```
$ sort -Vr kernels
       kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
       kernel-3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
       kernel-2.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64
```

If you are on MacOS, there is the option to install GNU tools with `homebrew`.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to get only highest one as o/p? "kernel-3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64" ~ I achieved using "tail -1" thanks

Comment: @jp922898 What is "o/p"?  If it means highest-first, then use the `-r` option to sort in reverse order.

Comment: @John1024 I think jp... meant "output" when she wrote "o/p". Gotta save those 3 chars - they don't grow on trees y'know :-).